# как в cmd настроить фильтр для отображения только тех файлов, которые начинаются с прописных букв

Tags: bash, cmd

Нужно настроить фильтр для отображения только тех файлов, которые начинаются с прописных букв в cmd и bash

Comment: Отображения где? И вы же в курсе, что в Windows нет отличия для строчных и прописных букв в именах файлов?

Comment: В командной строке

Comment: Файлы TEXT2,text,3text3

Comment: Надо, чтобы он вывел text

Comment: В командной строке нет никаких фильтров файлов. Так что и настраивать там нечего. Если имеется в виду что-то иное - будьте более точны и аккуратны в формулировках.

Comment: Надо через регулярку

Comment: В командной строке нет никаких регулярок.

Comment: Можно через батник, мне просто нужна команда

Comment: У меня три файла, надо вывести только с прописной

Comment: Уже bash появился. О какой ОС идет речь?

Comment: Сначала в винде, потов в центосе)))))

Comment: А вы в курсе, что это две принципиально различные ОС?

Comment: В курсе, то в курсе, мне нужны решения в обоих осях

Comment: Система — это она, поэтому в *обеих*. :)

Answer (score 2):

dir /B | findstr /r "^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"

Answer (score 0):

Специфика файловой системы Windows такова, что она не чувствительна к регистру, и те же файлы, чьи имена начинаются с заглавной буквы могут отображаться командой `dir /l` в нижнем регистре. Однако, начиная с Windows 10 можно задать учет регистра для каталога:

```
fsutil file setCaseSensetiveInfo "C:\некая папка" enable
```

Отключить:

```
fsutil file setCaseSensetiveInfo "C:\некая папка" disable
```

Из вышесказанного можно сделать следующий вывод. Если версия Windows ниже десятки, достаточно команды `dir /l`, так как регистр не принципиален, в противном случае было бы неплохо предварительно использовать команду `fsutil file queryCaseSensitiveInfo "C:\некая папка"` дабы удостовериться, что регистр имеет значение, и если это так - комбинировать `dir` с `findstr`.

Что касается `Linux`, вариантов может быть несколько. Наиболее предпочтительным на мой взгляд будет:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[[:lower:]]*'
```

Во-первых, ищутся именно файлы, во-вторых, команда легка для восприятия, и, скажем, если потребуется найти файлы, начинающиеся с заглавной буквы, достаточно будет `[[:lower:]]*` заменить на `[[:upper:]]*`, ровно как и проще управлять рекурсией.